# A function $f:M\to N$ where $M$ and $N$ are finite sets containing $m$ and $n$ elements respectively.

Tags: combinatorics, functions

How many injective, surjective and bijective functions does there exist given the right conditions on $m$ and $n$?

I've seen the proof/solution for surjection however I couldn't find any threads for injection and bijection. My answer is as follows:

Injection: If $m>n$ there are none. If instead $m \le n$, there exists at least one element in N for every element in $M$. However, for each element chosen in N there is one less available, so the choices are $n,n-1,n-2,\dots,n-m$. Therefore, $n!$ is the amount of choices but I have to remove $(n-m)!$ choices. Consequently, the choices are $_nP_m$.

Bijection is simply the case where $n=m$ such that $_nP_n=n!$

Comment: Yes.  It is worth pointing out as well the notation for [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) $n\frac{m}{~}$ and that the set of injective functions from $M$ to $N$ is also written by some authors as $N\frac{M}{~}$ leading to the convenient result that $|N\frac{M}{~}|=|N|\frac{|M|}{~}$

Comment: I'm a bit surprised you found the result for surjections before the one for injections.  I find that requires a bit more effort.  The total there being $\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}m\\n\end{smallmatrix}\right\}n!$ surjections from $M$ to $N$ where $\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}m\\n\end{smallmatrix}\right\}$ is the [stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  (*You may also have seen this written with inclusion-exclusion*).  Additional suggested reading: [Stanley's Twelvefold Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way)

Comment: Appreciate the answer! I had no idea factorials were such a big topic, I'll read in to your links! @JMoravitz